# Vscode terminal not loading .zshrc on startup! How can I fix this?

Tags: zsh, visual-studio-code, zshrc

I have `code` package installed my on *Pop!_OS 21.10*, and recently after opening the integrated terminal, I noticed that it does not load my `.zshrc`.

Here are my settings:

```json
 "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
```

Note: Everything works fine when I run `source .zshrc` after opening the integrated terminal, but it does not load the profile automatically. Anyone knows why?

Comment: I don't know vscode, but can you put a full command line into the terminal setting? In this case I would do a `zsh -x`, to better see **what** zsh is actually doing on startup. What happens if you try this? Another point to consider: Do you accidentally have `ZDOTDIR` set (i.e. do you get something when you do a `echo $ZDOTDIR`?).

Comment: The `ZDOTDIR` was the point, Thanks @user1934428

Comment: Farhad, you have made the edit to my answer, although I approved that, but please don't make these kinds of edits, since the question already have python tag, so anyone can see from there, I have used pre tag and strong tag for focus on particular thing :) given you some points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already defined `ZDOTDIR` variable incorrectly pointing to `.cache` in my `.zshrc`, which made `code` to look over there for my config file.

The problem is solved now by defining `ZDOTDIR` as my `$HOME` directory.

### Update:

-- $HOME is the default so I just deleted my definition.

Comment: $HOME is the default for ZDOTDIR, so you could equally well simply unset the variable.

Comment: Yes that's a better idea

Comment: That worked for me.
Also: relogin from your TTY

Answer (score 9):

The current version of VSCode may ignore your `.zshrc` in the following situation:

- the option `Terminal › Integrated › Shell Integration: Enabled` (`terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled`) is checked
- the environment variable `$ZDOTDIR` is empty

Consider the [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143061#issuecomment-1042785423) and add the following line to your `settings.json`:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": { "zsh": { "path": "/bin/zsh", "args": ["-l", "-i"] } }
```

(`osx` in the setting's name is for MacOS, `linux` is for Linux)

Comment: It seems that with the recent update the `zsh` shell is not executed as a login shell hence it stopped reading my `~/.zprofile` which defined a different `ZDOTDIR` than default and so was not able to find the `.zshrc`. This answer fixed it for me.

Comment: this breaks the restored terminals (or 'persistent sessions' you name it) feature

Comment: Thank you! Asked GitHub copilot repeatedly about this but it kept pointing me to bad settings. This answer, including the link to the github issue worked a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and had also to manually execute

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

And ***long story short*** I solved it with a ***symlink*** by executing

```
ln -s ../.zshrc $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
```

Explanation how I came up with this solution and why I prefer this solution over two other possible solutions that are working and have been proposed above:

Following the documentation in

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/shell-integration

I've added the following line at the end of my `~/.zshrc`

```
[[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "vscode" ]] && . "$(code --locate-shell-integration-path zsh)"
```

which sources a script whenever VSCode gets started.

But that alone didn't fix that particular problem.

When looking at that script by executing

```
less "$(code --locate-shell-integration-path zsh)"
```

I found following line that caused this problem

```
. $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
```

with `$USER_ZDOTDIR` pointing to `~/.zsh`
The variable `$USER_ZDOTDIR` even sets the variable `$ZDOTDIR`
So setting

```
USER_ZDOTDIR=${HOME}
```

would have solved it, but since `$ZDOTDIR` is very crucial and pointing it to `${HOME}` could break things by missing the `${HOME}/.zsh/.zshenv` with `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` pointing to it.

For example, in my `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` scripts are *sourced* which paths are added to the `$PATH` variable in (e.g. `$HOME/.cargo/bin`)

To have a fast look on that script I recommend executing

```
cat "$(code --locate-shell-integration-path zsh)" | grep -E '\bUSER_ZDOTDIR\b'
```

results in (Attention: these are not consecutive lines)

```
ZDOTDIR=$USER_ZDOTDIR
    HISTFILE=$USER_ZDOTDIR/.zsh_history
    if [[ $options[norcs] = off  && -f $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc ]]; then
        ZDOTDIR=$USER_ZDOTDIR
        . $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
if [[ $options[login] = off && $USER_ZDOTDIR != $VSCODE_ZDOTDIR ]]; then
    ZDOTDIR=$USER_ZDOTDIR
```

(Attention: these are not consecutive lines) with

```
cat "$(code --locate-shell-integration-path zsh)" | grep -E '\bUSER_ZDOTDIR\b' -A 2 -B 2
```

you get these lines with some context! And by **increasing the numbers** at the end you **can display more context**

But you can see the line causing the problem

```
. $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
```

and

```
cat "$(code --locate-shell-integration-path zsh)" | grep -E '\bZDOTDIR\b' # -A 1 -B 1
```

you can have a look concerning the effects of `$ZDOTDIR`.
Remove the `#` and change the number after `-A` and `-B` to include more or less context.

You also don't have to be concerned about your `$HISTFILE` in spite of the line

```
HISTFILE=$USER_ZDOTDIR/.zsh_history
```

which stays the same with this solution as long it's set in your `~/.zshrc` file and overwrites this assignment.

---

**Off-Topic but potentially useful**

While searching for the solution which fits the most I found out that you could have a different history files for VSCode only by adding also

```
[[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "vscode" ]] && HISTFILE=${ZDOTDIR}/.vscode_history
```

which can be very **useful for shell-intensive projects like npm, yarn etc.** are.

***But the commands have to be executed inside the VSCode-Shell to end up in said history file***.

Since I have created⁽¹⁾ two aliases which are useful for myself and possible for others, too

You can also have history files which are only assigned to a single project.

All the following extra history files are contained in the `$ZDOTDIR` folder

This alias temporarily sets `$HISTFILE` according to the folder you're in and should only executed in the project's root folder

```
alias set-project-histfile='eval "[[ \"\$TERM_PROGRAM\" == \"vscode\" ]] && HISTFILE=\${ZDOTDIR}/\$(echo \$PWD | rev  | cut -d '/' -f1  | rev)_history"'
```

while the following alias writes the `$HISTFILE` assignment which is like above also **only in effect when using the VSCode terminal** at the end of $HOME/.zshrc making it permanent until this line is deleted manually

```
alias set-project-histfile-permanent='echo "[[ \"\$TERM_PROGRAM\" == \"vscode\" ]] && HISTFILE=\${ZDOTDIR}/\$(echo \$PWD | rev  | cut -d '/' -f1  | rev)_history" >> ${HOME}/.zshrc'
```

Keep in mind that this `$HISTFILE` assignment has the effect that each project you're working with VSCode has its own history file in the `$ZDOTDIR` folder.

**Examples:**

```
$ZDOTDI/projectFoo_history
$ZDOTDIR/projectBar_history
$ZDOTDIR/projectFoobar_history
$ZDOTDIR/Fugazi_history
…
$HOME/.zsh/Fugazi_history
```

and the command you execute in VSCode's terminal end up in these history file instead of the usual one.

Comment: `ln -s ../.zshrc $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc` ; surely if $ZDOTDIR *doesn't* point to your home folder this is simply bad advice and the *correct* advice would be to figure out why it is misconfigured?